# How to send requests to another computer with python

Tags: python, networking, request

Basically I have a chatroom which I'm going to turn into a network (I know it doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense) but basically I was wondering if I could have a python script capture all outgoing requests on a computer and instead send it to another computer (c2). I then want c2 to make the request on it's own. This is a watered down explanation of what I'm doing but any help will be great!

Comment: What you describe sounds like a firewall or network monitoring system. These are big non-trivial projects, especially when encryption and ssl certificates come into play. Or you mean to set up a proxy, and then your app routes to that? Either way, you'll need to provide some code for people to help you. See [ask].

Comment: Im trying to make a proxy but 3 times over basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can set up a remote machine and get its IP address. On the remote machine you can set up this code:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('*CHANGE TO SERVER IP*', portnumber)
print("Starting on %s port %s" % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        data = connection.recv(999)
        # You have received the data, do what you want with it.
    except:
        connection.close()
```

And on the client machine:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('*INSERT SERVER IP*', portnumber)
print('Connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)

while True:
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(server_address)
        message=input('Message: ')
        if message=='quit':
            break
        sock.sendall(message)
    except:
        break
sock.close()
```

The server side code also works as client side for receiving information.

Comment: Thanks, will get to work right away.

Comment: Have you looked into configuring DNS settings?

Comment: No I have not. Thank you I'll look into that asap